# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore"

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I'm having an issue when running pod install in my flutter project for IOS.

I did not change any dependencies but there seems to be a problem with the Firebase/Firestore version.
In particular the error i'm getting is:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Firestore (= 10.15.0)

  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from .symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios) was resolved to 4.13.3, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (= 10.18.0)

Specs satisfying the Firebase/Firestore (= 10.15.0), Firebase/Firestore (= 10.18.0) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] Automatically assigning platform iOS with version 12.0 on target Runner because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform
```

Anyone facing the same issue?

I've already tried every command i know:

```
pod install
pod update
pod repo update
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

I updgraded flutter and all the packages, and recreated the podfile and podfile.lock files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the minimum ios platform in the Podfile is at least 11:

`platform :ios, '11.0'`